# Why is grep displaying command as part of output?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have written a bash script that finds any executable files in our scripts directory, then performs a grep on the resulting files to display a description, if it was included in the file.

A "description" is identified in each file as a line beginning with "# DESC:"

For some reason, the script also includes the grep command that is being run (but only once). Does anyone know why this is?

Script and output shown below. Why does the second line in the output happen?

### Script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find any FILES that are EXECUTABLE in the SCRIPTS 
# directory and display any description, if there is one

find /opt/scripts/. -perm -111 -type f -maxdepth 1 | while read line ;
do
 file=$(basename "$line")
 printf "\033[1m%10s\033[0m : " $file
 grep "# DESC:"  "$line" | cut -c 9-
done
```

### Output

```
      desc : Displays all the scripts and their descriptions
 DESC:"  "$line" | cut -c 9-
  showhelp : Displays the script help file
      test : Script to perform system testing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reason

Presumably your grepping script is also in /opt/scripts?

So it finds itself, and finds the grep subject '#DESC' and prints that.

You could fix that by adding a # DESC line to the top of your grep script, and just outputting the first result found by each grep using 'grep -m1'

```
grep -m1 '# DESC' "$line" | cut -c 9-
```

<humour>Otherwise its just turtles all the way down...  ;-) </humour>

### Alternative Fix

You could also improve the grep by using a regular expression and anchoring to the beginning of the line:

```
egrep -m1 '^# DESC' "$line" | cut -c 9-
```

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid now. That was it exactly.

Modified the script to match only at the start of a line instead of anywhere in the line.

Thank you!